# Accessing CI's config file from a plugin's config file

Tags: php, codeigniter, plugins, config

I am trying to centralize all deployment specific changes into CI's main config file and then have "lesser" config files (like a plugin's) read it from here.

In this specific instance:

I have CKEditor/CKFinder as plugins to my Codeigniter app. I would like to read values from CI's main config file from CKFinder's config file so that I can get at the baseURL.

In order to tell CKFinder where to look for images, you need to specify a baseURL in its config.php file. I would rather it read the baseURL from my main config file and append an image directory to this instead of modifying CKFinder's file directly.

I tried the following in CKFinder's config.php file to no avail:

```
$baseUrl=$this->$config['base_url'].'assets/my_images/';
```

Please lead me to the light!

Mmiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna read  `base_url` you can do something like this:

```
$baseUrl = base_url().'assets/my_images/';
```

Instead if you wanna reach a config-item, you can do this.

```
$this->config->item('your_constant');
```

and in the config file something like:

```
$config['your_constant'] = "your string";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I'll use xiankai's suggestion to get my baseurl but for other config items I do need to access as well, you've given me the solution!

Comment: Accept the answer if solved your problem to help other guys with your same problem @user1072910

Comment: My apologies about returning to this after such a long time - but in the CKFinder config file, "$this" is not in the object context. So actually I'm not able to refer to my main base_url or any main config items.

Comment: try to read this article http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/12/13/cakephp-how-to-ckfinder-configuration-management-using-component/ @user1072910

Answer (score 0):

You can use `site_url` which was intended to be an extension of `base_url` but for relative paths.

```
$baseUrl = site_url('/assets/my_images');
```

Comment: Thanks - I will go ahead and use this suggestion for setting my baseurl. I am kicking myself for not thinking about site_url()! Much obliged